# Using small brackets twice?

Tags: functions

Why is it not syntactically wrong to write (f(x)), where [f(x)] still exists? I find this often in composite functions, such as the above, and trigonometric equations, where (sin(x)) is used instead of [sin(x)]. Of course there is an instance where (sinx) is used, so more confusion there.

Comment: Usually, [a] is meant to be the greatest integer below a, so I think that is the reason why [f(x)] may not be used.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez: The usual modern notation for the floor of $a$ is actually $\lfloor a\rfloor$, not $[a]$, though one does still see the latter. As for the question, $(f(x))$ and $[f(x)]$ are generally synonymous: if you can use one, you can usually use the other. But there is almost never any reason to write either of them, unless $f(x)$ is itself a function, and one needs to write $(f(x))(y)$ or the like. And while changing the type of bracket may make the expression easier to parse, this is certainly not a syntactic issue.

Comment: The only time I ever use, algebraically, [] instead of (), is if I'm already using too many ()'s. They are simply grouping symbols, unless additional context is implied.